# Is throwing exceptions without catching them bad?

Tags: php, exception, error-handling

In my MVC router I got something like:

```
if (class_exists('Controller')) {
    $controller = new Controller();
} else {
    throw new Exception('Controller not found.');
}
```

And I'm actually never catching this exception when it occurs. I just have it there so that it shows me an error so I can look it up and fix it.

I have a feeling this is a bad way of using exceptions, isn't it?

If so, what would be a better example of using exceptions?

Comment: Catch at the top level of your script and display an appropriate neatly formatted message

Comment: What Mark Baker said. Do you want your visitors to see (maybe sensible) data in form of ugly php exceptions?

Comment: Looks good for developing a site, not so much for putting it live.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allowing exceptions to go un-caught can lead to some messy situations. The worst-case scenario is that the exception can cause a stack trace to be output to the client, and the stack trace might contain sensitive information. For example:

```
class Foo {
    public function __construct($username, $password) {
        throw new Exception('oh noes');
    }
}

$bar = new Foo('Sammitch', 'bologna123');
```

Which generates the following output

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'oh noes' in /home/sammitch/tmp/test.php:6
Stack trace:
#0 /home/sammitch/tmp/test.php(11): Foo->__construct('Sammitch', 'bologna123')
#1 {main}
  thrown in /home/sammitch/tmp/test.php on line 6
```

The exception could be thrown many more levels deep in the stack, in code completely unrelated to what requires those credentials.

Best practice in this case is to use [`set_exception_handler()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php) to define a function that will handle uncaught exceptions in a way you define explicitly. eg:

```
set_exception_handler(function($e){ echo $e->getMessage(); });
```

Which makes the above example output simply: `oh noes`

A better solution would be to log the exceptions to a file and/or notify an administrator.

Answer (score 0):

No, that's a good way to use them. At least if you ever hit this error you'll have a clear error message to work with. Whether it should be caught or not depends on the context.

Presumably, in production you don't actually display error, but it should still be in the error log (again it depends on which framework you are using, etc.).

Comment: So, in production I would then catch it and show a user friendly message and log the error?

Comment: Yes, you could for instance have a global handler for uncaught exceptions using http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php and display a generic error page to the user (while logging the complete error).